# How to get a value of string from first class and use in second class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to get value of a string from first class and I want to use in second class but I don't know how to do it.

> I just want to access first class value and use in second class.

**I've already tried getter and setter method:**

```
  tk = tkinter('rohit')
  print(tk.__getattribute__('length'))
```

**This is my code:**

```
class values:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
    def run(self):
        name = self.root # <----|I want these values and print in splash class
        age = 20         # <----|
        length = '152cm' # <----| 

class splash:
    def __init__(self, name, age, length):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.size = length
    def show(self):
       print('Name:%s, Age:%s, length:%s' % (self.name, self.age, self.length)



# call
tk = tkinter('rohit')

tk.?
splash = splash(?)

splash.show()
```

**I excepted result:**

```
Name:rohit, Age:33, length:152cm
```

Comment: try class splash (object): , with return on the def show(self)

Comment: don't use the same name for instance and class name - `splash = splash()`. There is good rule to use "UpperCaseNames" for classes - `class Splash()`, `class Values()` and then you have `splash = Splash()`. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: first create instance of values - `item = Values()` and later use it as argument in class `Splash` - `splash = Splash(item.root, item.age, item.length)` but they can't be local variable but class variable with `self.`. If you will create `Splash` inside `Values` then you can use `self.` - `splash = Splash(self.root, self.age, self..length)`

Answer (score 1):

First: use `UpperCaseNames` for names of classes - `class Values`, `class Splash` - to easier recognize class in code and not overwrite variables with different content - ie. `splash = Splash()`

---

Use `self.` in `Values` to keep values and then you can create instance of Values to use it in `Splash()`

```
items = Values('rohit')
items.run()
splash = Splash(items.name, items.age, items.length)
```

Full code:

```
class Values:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def run(self):
        self.name = self.root # <----|I want these values and print in splash class
        self.age = 20         # <----|
        self.length = '152cm' # <----| 

class Splash:

    def __init__(self, name, age, length):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.length = length

    def show(self):
       print('Name:%s, Age:%s, length:%s' % (self.name, self.age, self.length))

items = Values('rohit')
items.run()
splash = Splash(items.name, items.age, items.length)
```

Or use `Splash()` direclty in `run()`

```
class Values:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def run(self):
        name = self.root # <----|I want these values and print in splash class
        age = 20         # <----|
        length = '152cm' # <----| 
        splash = Splash(name, age, length)
        splash.show()

class Splash:

    def __init__(self, name, age, length):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.length = length

    def show(self):
       print('Name:%s, Age:%s, length:%s' % (self.name, self.age, self.length))

items = Values('hello')
items.run()
```